# CompressBackupUtil does not backup blobs

Tags: java, xodus

I have this code

```
    Environment env = manager.getEnvironment(xodusRoot, appId);
    final File backupFile = CompressBackupUtil.backup(env, new File(env.getLocation(), "backups"), null, true);

    Representation representation = new FileRepresentation(backupFile, MediaType.APPLICATION_ZIP);
    Disposition disposition = new Disposition(Disposition.TYPE_ATTACHMENT);
    disposition.setFilename(backupFile.getName());
    representation.setDisposition(disposition);
    setStatus(Status.SUCCESS_OK);
```

It works but the problem is that the blobs are not getting into the backup. What could be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Environments](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Environments) API doesn't allow blobs. To deal with blobs, you have to have an instance of `PersistentEntityStore`. It is `Backupable`, as well as `Environment` is. If you pass the instance of `PersistententityStore` (instead of `Environment)` to `CompressBackupUtil.backup(...)`, then you will get backup files with blobs.